# How to find the solution for this equation?

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I wanted to find the value that makes the  derivative of the following function equal to $0$
$$X(e)=v_i \sqrt{1-e^2}\left(\frac{v_ie}{g}+\sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g}}\right)$$
After deriving and simplifying i reached the following
$$\frac{v_i[g \left(v_i(1-2e^2) \sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }-2ey_i \right)+v_i^2e(1-2e^2)]}{g^2\sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }\sqrt{1-e^2}}$$
But I am having a hard time trying to find the values of $e$ that make the derivative equal to $0$.

$$g[v_i(1-2e^2) \sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }-2ey_i]+v_i^2e(1-2e^2)=0$$

Comment: $(1-2e^2)$ is a factor.

Comment: @paul it is not in the first term on both sides so not sure if taking it out would make stuff easier or the fraction  will make calculating harder

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I wasn't looking where the square root finished!

Comment: @Paul np thanks for the suggestion it is a long equation so understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by rearranging it to get rid of the square root (I'm dropping the subscripts because I'm lazy):

$$\begin{eqnarray} g\left[v(1-2e^2)\sqrt{\frac{v^2 e^2}{g^2} + \frac{2y}{g}} - 2ey \right] + v^2 e(1 - 2e^2) & = & 0 \\
gv(1-2e^2)\sqrt{\frac{v^2 e^2}{g^2} + \frac{2y}{g}} & = & 2egy - v^2 e(1 - 2e^2) \\
g^2v^2(1-2e^2)^2\left[\frac{v^2 e^2}{g^2} + \frac{2y}{g}\right] & = & 4e^2g^2y^2 - 4e^2gyv^2(1-2e^2) + v^4e^2(1-2e^2)^2
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then notice that the first term on the left cancels the last term on the right. With some more simplification, you can reduce the whole thing to a quadratic expression in $2e^2$ that you can then solve via normal means.

Comment: finally it worked ,the first time I kept  $2^2$ instead of substituting it which cased a lot of miscalculations  , after substituting It I kept a sign positive which kept $e^4$ and gave me wrong results , after rechecking and tracking down my steps I reached the outcome I wanted

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1:

Removing constants $(y_i,g, v)$ and defining new non-dimensional constant

$$ p^2=\frac{2y_i g}{v^2} $$

$$ Y(e)= \sqrt{1-e^2}(e+ \sqrt{e^2+p^2})$$
Applying Chain Rule

$$ \frac{e+\sqrt{e^2+p^2}}{\sqrt{1-e^2}} = \frac{(1+\dfrac{e}{\sqrt{e^2+p^2}})\sqrt{1-e^2}}{e} $$

Cross multiplying, the $f(e)$ to be solved is

$$e({e+\sqrt{e^2+p^2}})= (1-e^2)(1+\dfrac{e}{\sqrt{e^2+p^2}})$$

Resulting in a simpler equation

$$ \frac{1-e^2}{e}=\sqrt{e^2+p^2}$$

EDIT2

To continue: Squaring and simplifying

$$ p^2e^2 +2 e^2-1=0 $$

has a solution of the quadratic

$$ e= \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+p^2}}{2p^2}$$

from which the negative value is discarded.

Comment: Thx for your solution from what i see no errors crept into it , yet the equation is different from the one in question  even when i substitute the term you choose as A i get a different equation and in return a different derivative

Comment: Sorry, instead of correcting it again I had re-edited, please see.

Comment: I appreciate both your time and your unique way of thinking ,It surely does make the equation simpler and by that it makes  finding the solution easier , yet I had to accept @ConMan answer since the approach keeps ( y ,g, v )which  though are constants  they are shells for whatever value they hold so when I solve for e I have to get it in respect to those values  , and the second   me not being that good at using chain rule ,so not being able to absorb everything fully , but once again you answer surely is very useful  and I thank you for it  sincerely.

Comment: Ok, I added a step more to obtain a simple result at the end. A numerical example with plot of  $f(e) $ and the $e$ at minimum/maximum value may help  to check further. Also Chain Rule: If u(x)/v(x)
 is constant then that also equals u′(x)/v′(x).

Comment: Thank you a lot :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share the  the answer to the question with detailed steps  and the things I had trouble with , in case someone encounters the same problems hope this will be helpful ,

so first the equation was in fact
$$X(\theta)=v_icos(\theta)\left(\frac{v_isin(\theta)}{g}+\sqrt{\frac{v_i^2sin(\theta)^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g}}\right)+x_i$$
where 0<\theta<90

I went and substituted $ sin(\theta)$ with $e$  and used the chain rule
so we have $$\frac{\delta x}{\delta e}\frac{\delta e}{\delta \theta}$$
now $sin(\theta)$ can't be equal to zero in the period given so we know that if we want  $$\frac{\delta x}{\delta \theta}=0$$  then $$\frac{\delta x}{\delta e} \text{ would =0 }$$

the derivation is a bit long took me a page from here  but it would be equal to the following
$$\frac{v_i[g \left(v_i(1-2e^2) \sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }-2ey_i \right)+v_i^2e(1-2e^2)]}{g^2\sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }\sqrt{1-e^2}}$$
now here $$g \left(v_i(1-2e^2) \sqrt{\frac{v_i^2e^2}{g^2}+\frac{2y_i}{g} }-2ey_i \right)+v_i^2e(1-2e^2)=0$$
$$\begin{eqnarray}
gv(1-2e^2)\sqrt{\frac{v^2 e^2}{g^2} + \frac{2y}{g}} & = & 2egy - v^2 e(1 - 2e^2) \\
g^2v^2(1-2e^2)^2\left[\frac{v^2 e^2}{g^2} + \frac{2y}{g}\right] & = & 4e^2g^2y^2 - 4e^2gyv^2(1-2e^2) + v^4e^2(1-2e^2)^2
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$v^4e^2(1-2e^2) + 2ygv^2(1-2e^2)^2  = 4e^2g^2y^2 - 4e^2gyv^2(1-2e^2) + v^4e^2(1-2e^2)^2$$

$$ 2ygv^2(1-2e^2)^2  = 4e^2g^2y^2 - 4e^2gyv^2(1-2e^2) + $$
now my second mistake was continuing to simplify from here , the oversimplifying caused  more miscalculations I was left with terms like $e^4$ and they weren't getting deleted and even when substituting $2e^2=z$ I mistyped some signs  and  went on solving equations with sqrt of sqrt  and the results were wrong

now we divide by $2gy$  and substituting $z=2e^2$

$$ v^2(1-2e^2)^2  = 2e^2gy - 2e^2v^2(1-2e^2) + $$
$$ v^2(1-z)^2  = zgy - zv^2(1-z) + $$
$$ 0  =(-v^2z^2+v^2z^2)+2zv^2+ zgy - zv^2-v^2 $$
$$ 2zv^2+ zgy - zv^2-v^2=0 $$
$$ z(gy+2v^2-v^2)-v^2 \\ z(gy+v^2)-v^2  \\ 2e^2(gy+v^2)-v^2 \\ e = \frac{0 \pm \sqrt{0- 4*2(gy+v^2)*-v^2}}{2*2(gy+v^2)}  $$
$$  e = \pm \sqrt{\frac{ 8(gy+v^2)*-v^2}{16(gy+v^2)^2}}  \\e = \pm \sqrt{\frac{ v^2}{2(gy+v^2)}}$$
we divide both numerator and denominator by $v^2$
$$ e = \pm \sqrt{\frac{ 1}{2(\frac{gy}{v^2}+1)}}$$
finally e is equal to sin in the period ]0,90[ so we take the positive value only .